A Nightmare on Elm Street (1984) - why have the music and effects been altered?
I recently had a chance to see the 1984 version of "A Nightmare on Elm Street" on Netflix and noticed something startlingly obvious: many important areas of music and sound effects had been omitted. I had this movie on VHS when I was 12, so I watched it over and over again, and it became one of those movies I just knew by heart. Seeing it again all these year later, those missing pieces really stand out.
Examples:

Rocks being thrown at Tina’s window (sounds is altered)
Freddy calling Tina’s name in the alley (sound voice is altered)
Freddy jumping out from behind the birch tree that Tina runs past (music effects removed)
Rod jumping out of the bushes to grab Nancy (music effects removed)
When Nancy first encounters Freddy in the school boiler room and asks, “Who are you?” (music effects removed)
Nancy being chased by Freddy and knocks over a metal trash can (sound is removed)

There are a number of others, but I just want to know why? These sound effects and musical additions created the tension needed in those scenes. I know we live in a time where everything needs to be remastered, HD, enhanced, etc., but there's simply no good reason for these changes in the film.
Does anyone have insight about why this was done?

I've seen many oldies like that with bad sound, and it's probably just about time and money (if not rights). The master recording aged bad when they needed to digitalize the copy. Can't remember where I read about that though...

To add surround sound instead of mono effects; https://www.homecinemachoice.com/content/nightmare-elm-street-collection

@Paulie_D - no Mandela effect here. I'm 1000% certain.

@OldPadawan - interesting thoughts about the music and rights. Charles Bernstein did the music, so you’d think that an original film that launched a massive franchise would be able to preserve the rights. It’s depressing cuz as it’s central — or at least I say it’s central — to the movie you get a different vibe when it’s not there. And these changes would’ve been done when Wes was still alive. ‍♂️

@Valoram - but again, it’s only certain sounds at specific moments. I don’t know why switching from mono to surround would matter.

@MattSmith my experience of the Mandela effect is that the percentage of certainty may be inversely proportionate to reality: I have memories of artworks that are so pristine that my mind says it's a clear proof of the multiverse that not only the physical artifact but the recollections of my family all disagree with recollection

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TzXz3fco3U and https://www.hometheaterforum.com/community/threads/a-nightmare-on-elm-street-1984.293426/

“there's simply no good reason for these changes in the film.” That’s never stopped anyone. Think of all the time and money that went into making the special editions of the Star Wars films. Totally unnecessary, but they did it anyway.

@BCdotWEB - yes, this is it. The transition to stereo. That's odd for sure, that video has a number of the discrepancies. I hope they decide to restore the original.
